# How to see results of all Flutter tests on the command line, not just the summary?

Tags: flutter-test

From the command line (MacOS) and in my case either the terminal app or Visual Code terminal, when I run flutter test, all the tests are run and pass but I only see the *All tests passed!* summary at the end - what I want to see is the whole list during, and after. What’s suppressing the output?

Answer (score 11):

I was looking for the same thing. This does the trick:

`flutter test -r expanded`

Found from the help command using `flutter test --help`

Answer (score 4):

It is just a matter of providing some flags and parameters:

- For showing a **separate line** for each update: `flutter test -r expanded`.
  May be preferred when logging into a file or in continuous integration.
- For showing a  machine-readable format -**json**- `flutter test -r json`.
- For showing all the **shell commands executed**: `flutter test --verbose`.

For more options: `flutter test --help`

Answer (score -1):

I think flutter test --verbose could help, but this is most likely more then you want. Additionally, you could use VSCode or Android Studios Testing Suite for that.

[image: Visual Studio Code Testing Suite]

Regarding why the output does not print into the console, I assume that this is by design. Dart / Flutter Test framework reduce the time consumption of successful tests so, there is no need to print statements.